# How to use a custom dialog in all of my application in android

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog and i have many activities... I need to call the same dailog in all the activities...currently i have written the code in each of the activity but this is not the right way... Can any one help me in this

Comment: Do you believe in static methods?

Comment: creating custom dialog is quite tricky but this link will helpful http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok below is my way of implementing dialog its in a static class so I can call it from any activity when I need

```
public static void showProgressDialog(Context mContext, String text, boolean cancellable)
{
    removeDialog();
    mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View layout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null);
    mDialog.setContentView(layout);

    TextView mTextView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    if (text.equals(""))
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        mTextView.setText(text);

    mDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            switch (keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    });

    mDialog.setCancelable(cancellable);

    mDialog.show();
}

public static void removeDialog()
{
    if (mDialog != null)
        mDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: can you show how do you call it in your activities?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a class and within that create a static method(say displayDialog), and within this, copy paste the code that displays your dialog. Now call this static method from anywhere in your project. But you might have to pass the context of the calling activity to the static method.

```
public class dialogClass {

static Dialog dialog=null;
public static void exitApp_Dialog(Context context,String title,String message){

     AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
      alertbox.setTitle("Warning");
     alertbox.setMessage("Exit Application?");
     alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
             activity.finish();
         }
     });
     alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

         } 
     });
     alertbox.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should regroup the code that builds the `Dialog` in a helper class.
Below is an excerpt of a `DialogHelper` I have built for myself and that I use to show my applications' help files.

```
public class DialogHelper {

public static AlertDialog showHelp(final Context ctx, final int resTitle, final int resFilename, final int resOk, final int resViewOnline, final int resOnlineUrl) {
        final WebView webview = new WebView(ctx);
        webview.loadUrl(ctx.getString(resFilename));

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setTitle(resTitle)
                .setView(webview)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(resOk, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(resViewOnline, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()         {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(ctx.getString(resOnlineUrl));
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        ctx.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            );

            final AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
            dlg.show();

            return dlg;
        }
    }

    ... other kinds of dialog take place here ...
}
```

This way I just call

```
DialogHelper.showHelp(context, R.string.helpTitle, R.string.localizedFilename, R.string.labelOk, R.string.labelViewOnlineHelp, R.string.onlineHelpUrl);
```

from all my applications. That's a lot of parameters but this is workable.

There is a non-nice thing in that code: I use `setNegativeButton()` for something else than its intended purpose. This is something I should refactor, but this doesn't change anything in the approach.

About the parameters of `showHelp()`: they are `final` as they are used in the anonymous classes built within the method. This is a requirement of the compiler.